# instantiating class gives that the name does not exist

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn OOP by creating a small program that reads a list of people and outputs only those who are older than 30 using two classes Person and PollParticipant. I am instantiating a new person from my person class and adding name and age: 
`Person person = new Person(name,age);`, which are defined in a constructor, but when I do so it gives me an error that `the name 'name' does not exist in the current context`. My fields are set to public, so it should be able to access them, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my Person class:

```
namespace Poll_Opinion
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;

        public Person(string name, int age)
        {
            this.name = Name;
            this.age = Age;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.name;
            }

            set
            {
                this.name = value;
            }
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                return this.age;
            }

            set
            {
                this.age = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My poll participants class:

```
namespace Poll_Opinion
{
    class PollParticipant
    {
        public List<Person> pollParticipant;

        public PollParticipant()
        {
            this.pollParticipant = new List<Person>();
        }

        public void AddMember(Person participant)
        {
            this.pollParticipant.Add(participant);
        }

        public Person ShowOlderMembers()
        {
            return this.pollParticipant.OrderByDescending(p => p.age).First();

        }

    }
}
```

And my Program.cs where I make the instantiation:

```
namespace Poll_Opinion
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            PollParticipant pollparticipant = new PollParticipant();

            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                string[] input = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                int age = int.Parse(input[i]);

                Person person = new Person(name,age);
                pollparticipant.AddMember(person);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well when you're at `Person person = new Person(name,age);`, where do you expect that `name` is coming from? I think there's a misunderstanding about how properties/fields work.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between class members, and **parameters**

Comment: Also, your class constructor is using the wrong value for the assignment. You want to assign the parameter, not the existing property

Comment: @Broots Waymb It comes from the fields that I have defined in the class?

Comment: @MurrayJohnson - No it doesn't. That's not how fields/properties and constructors work.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues. The first is here:

```
Person person = new Person(name,age);
```

You try to pass `name` and `age` to the `Person` constructor but you have not instantiate them.

The second problem is in your constructor:

```
public Person(string name, int age)
{
    // this.name = Name;
    this.name = name;
    // this.age = Age;
    this.age = age;
}
```

You need to assign `name` parameter to `this.name` field, not `Name` property. In you case you assign `this.name` to `this.name`:

```
this.name = Name; // => where 'Name' get method return this.name

public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    set
    {
        this.name = value;
    }
}
```

By the way, you don't need a public field `name` (that should be private) in this case. Just do:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In C# the properties pratically already have an hidden private field.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that this class would be instantiated by something like `Person person = new Person("Bob", age);` or whatever. OP doesn't seem to understand how fields/properties work in regards to creating new objects.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is not defined in your Main() function when you are creating the Person objects.